# Get Azure Storage Account Key inside Powershell Function App

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-function-app, azure-storage-account

I am trying to get the Key of a Storage Account from inside a Powershell Function App under the same Resource Group "rg-mobileplans".

I am certain I have the correct Azure Context and when listing all the Storage Accounts I see the one I am trying to retrieve the key from - "stmobileplansstaging".

```
Write-Host ((Get-AzContext).Subscription)
Write-Host (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName rg-mobileplans).StorageAccountName
```

Output:

```
<Subscription ID Hidden for Privacy>
stmobileplansstaging storageaccountrgmob83d8
```

But when I try to get the key itself I get an error message that the Storage Account Could not be found.

```
Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName rg-mobileplans -AccountName stmobileplansstaging
```

Output:

```
ERROR: Get-AzStorageAccountKey : The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stmobileplansstaging ' under resource group 'rg-mobileplans' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
```

Keep in mind that I am running these commands from a Function App. Running them from Powershell works.

I have created a System Managed Identity for the Function App and gave it "Owner" access to the entire "rg-mobileplans" Resource Group and the "stmobileplansstaging" Storage Account.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what the problem is. In the script the storage account name is given through a tag. The name had a space at the end. When running the get / list storage account commands it's OK and the commands succeed because the name of the account is probably at the end, but for getting the key, underneath a POST call is being made and the URL looked something like "http://.../storage/stmobileplansstaging /rest-of-the-uri". Notice the space in the middle of the URI which broke everything.